# Programmatically change Actionbar title color in Gingerbread

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a requirement to programmatically change the actionbar title text color.

I use the following code to set the color in slightly different ways, depending on SDK version

```
int textColor = getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
        // Version 4+
        int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
        TextView abTitle = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
        if (abTitle != null) {
            abTitle.setTextColor(textColor);
        }
    } else {
        // Other versions
        TextView abTitle = (TextView) getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        if (abTitle != null) {
            abTitle.setTextColor(textColor);
        }
    }
```

It works fine on devices with SDK value 14 or greater. But, for Gingerbread devices, abTitle is always null so the color doesn't get set.

Does anyony have any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your `if/else` is wrong, It should look like

```
 int titleId;
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
      titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
  } else {
      titleId = R.id.action_bar_title;
  }
```

and then you should be able to get it directly through `findViewById`

Comment: @blackbelt action_bar_title works perfectly this way, but when I do this to get action_bar_subtitle system return null on Galaxy Tab(OS:Android 3.1)

Comment: @mr.boyfox I had lot of issues with Android 3.x. In the end I gave up with that

Comment: @blackbelt Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Have you used the support library?? As Actionbar is not supported below api level 11.

Comment: Hi there,Yes this is using ActionBarActivity